# Prove by induction that $a_{2m}=\frac{(0-b)(1+b)(2-b)(3+b)....(2m-1+b)}{(2m)!}a_0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, induction

This is part of another question with a given ODE:
$(1-x^2)y''-2xy'+b(b+1)y=0$.

Before my question I was asked to prove that if $y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ is analytic solution of the ODE around $x_0=0$ then:

$a_{n+2}=\frac{(n-b)(n+1+b)}{(n+2)(n+1)}a_n$

Now, im supposed to prove by induction using this. I got stuck because I can't figure out what to do with $a_0$

Comment: Maybe the question should say "Now show that if $a_0$ is any real number, and $a_0, a_1, ...$ are the coefficients of a series solution to the ODE, then $a_{2m} = \ldots$ for m = 0, 1,.... In short: you don't do ANYTHING with $a_0$, except to say: My claim $P(m)$ is that for $m = 0, 1, ...$, the formula $a_{2m} =  \frac{(0-b)(1+b)(2-b)(3+b)....(2m-1+b)}{(2m)!}a_0\ldots$ holds true. Let's first show that $P(0)$ is true. $P(0)$ says that $a_0 = \frac{1}{(2 \cdot 0)!} = a_0$, which is evidently true. Now let's suppose that for $m > 0$, we know $P(m-1)$ is true. We'll then show $P(m)$.

Comment: I still dont get it... where does $P(m)$ lead me to?
What i proved looks like "one part" of the multipication in the formula i need to prove

Answer (score 0):

Set $n=2m-2,\forall m=1,2,...$ at the given anadromic formula that describes $(a_n)$ and you get $$a_{2m}=\dfrac{(2m-p)(2m-1+b)}{2m\cdot(2m-1)},\ m=1,2,... $$
Now, if you write previous equations for all 1,2,...,m and then you multiply all of them you get the analytic form that describes the subsequence $(a_{2m})$ of $(a_n)$.